# Xamarin.iOS UIDocumentPickerViewController

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have a question regarding iOS document picker.

I have included iCloud container / enabled the iCloud for our provisioning. Also added the needed [Cloudkit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/data-cloud/intro-to-cloudkit) requirements for the Xamarin.iOS itself. However, I have a problem launching the popover menu to show the browse file menu for iOS.

```
var documentPicker = new UIDocumentPickerViewController(allowedUtis, UIDocumentPickerMode.Import);

documentPicker.DidPickDocument += DocumentPicker_DidPickDocument;
documentPicker.WasCancelled += DocumentPicker_WasCancelled;
documentPicker.DidPickDocumentAtUrls += DocumentPicker_DidPickDocumentAtUrls;
documentPicker.WasCancelled += DocumentPicker_WasCancelled;

private void DocumentPicker_DidPickDocumentAtUrls(object sender, UIDocumentPickedAtUrlsEventArgs e)
{
     var control = (UIDocumentPickerViewController)sender;
     foreach (var url in e.Urls)
         DocumentPicker_DidPickDocument(control, new UIDocumentPickedEventArgs(url));

         control.Dispose();
}
```

It seems like the event DidPickDocument / DidPickDocumentAtUrls event wouldn't launch, are there any needed options / permissions other than setting up my provisioning, entitlements, info.plist, for me to use the document picker of iOS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I recently did it and it works fine in my xamarin forms application :

```
private void ShowDocsPicker()
    {
        try
        {
            var docPicker = new UIDocumentPickerViewController(new string[]
            { UTType.Data, UTType.Content }, UIDocumentPickerMode.Import);
            docPicker.WasCancelled += DocPicker_WasCancelled;
            docPicker.DidPickDocumentAtUrls += DocPicker_DidPickDocumentAtUrls;
            var _currentViewController = GetCurrentUIController();
            if (_currentViewController != null)
                _currentViewController.PresentViewController(docPicker, true, null);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
          //Exception Logging
        }
    }
```

Get current UIViewController something like this :

```
  public UIViewController GetCurrentUIController()
    {
        UIViewController viewController;
        var window = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow;
        if (window == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        if (window.RootViewController.PresentedViewController == null)
        {
            window = UIApplication.SharedApplication.Windows
                     .First(i => i.RootViewController != null &&
                                 i.RootViewController.GetType().FullName
                                 .Contains(typeof(Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.Platform).FullName));
        }

        viewController = window.RootViewController;

        while (viewController.PresentedViewController != null)
        {
            viewController = viewController.PresentedViewController;
        }

        return viewController;
    }
```

Then add the doc selected event like this :

```
 private void DocPicker_DidPickDocumentAtUrls(object sender, UIDocumentPickedAtUrlsEventArgs e)
    {
     //Action to perform on document pick
    }
```

Revert in case of queries.

Comment: Hi my main problem is that the event documentPicker.DidPickDocumentAtUrls wouldn't launch, did you do anything beforehand like for entitlements, especially with provisioning. Thank you.

Comment: Try updating to my code and take a look if it works!

Comment: Sure man no problem in case you face any further issue let me know